# What is the best way to create new columns based on value of existing column of Pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame as follows, with about 1k distinct values in Category:

```
    Category     Value     
       a          0.1        
       b          1          
       c          100        
       d          20         
       a          0.5
```

What I expect:

1. split the numerical column "Value" into N bands between the minimum and maximum values: for the case above, let Nbands=10, they are 0.1-10, 10-20, 20-30, ..., 90-100.
2. create new columns based on Category_ValueBands combinations and sum up the values:

That is:

```
    Category     Value         a_1    a_2 ... a_10 ... d_10 
       a          0.1          0.6     ...     ...     ...
       b          1             0
       c          100           0
       d          20            0
       a          0.5          0.6             ...      0
```

What is the best way to make this with N bands for the numerical column "Value" and values of categorical column "Category"?

Comment: do you need to maintain the original df structure? you can do this by a groupby pretty easily if you just want counts.

Comment: Yes, I want to maintain the original df structure

Answer (score 1):

You could use [oneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) in scikit-learn.

But if you want to do it directly, maybe something like this...

load your data into a dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_csv('testData.csv')
```

Create a new col with required values...  you will later blow these out into your new column names, but for now they're values...  'a_0', 'a_1', etc.

```
newCol_1 = x.Category.values
newCol_2 = (x.Value / 10).astype(int).astype(str).values
x['newCol'] = newCol_1 + '_' + newCol_2
```

creates a new column with sums of your values.

```
newVals = x.ix[:, ['newCol', 'Value']].groupby('newCol').agg(np.sum)       # counts
newVals.columns = ['newVals']                                              # change column names
x = pd.merge(x, newVals, how='left', left_on='newCol', right_index=True)   # merge with df


x.ix[:,['newCol', 'newVals']]
Out[54]: 
  newCol  newVals
0    a_0      0.6
1    b_0      1.0
2   c_10    100.0
3    d_2     20.0
4    a_0      0.6
```

spread 'newCol' out into one column per category...

```
for col in np.unique(x.newCol):
    x[col] = 0.0
    idx = (x.newCol == col)
    x.ix[idx, col] = x.newVals[idx]


x
Out[56]: 
  Category  Value  Count newCol  newVals  a_0  b_0  c_10  d_2
0        a    0.1      2    a_0      0.6  0.6    0     0    0
1        b    1.0      3    b_0      1.0  0.0    1     0    0
2        c  100.0      1   c_10    100.0  0.0    0   100    0
3        d   20.0      4    d_2     20.0  0.0    0     0   20
4        a    0.5      5    a_0      0.6  0.6    0     0    0
```